# Openmdao testflo 1 failed case - (test_map.py:TestMap.test_comp_map) and 612 skipped cases

Tags: openmdao

I recently installed openmdao 3.16.0 using pip install. When I tried to run the unit test case (testflo openmdao -n 1), I see that 2680 have passed, 1 failed (test_map.py) and 612 cases have been skipped. This is the error message:

C:\Users\anuha\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openmdao\surrogate_models\tests\test_map.py:TestMap.test_comp_map ... FAIL (00:00:0.03, 142 MB)
C:\Users\anuha\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openmdao\utils\options_dictionary.py:332: OMDeprecationWarning:'train:Nc' is not a valid python name and will become an invalid option name in a future release. You can prevent this warning (and future exceptions) by declaring this option using a valid python name.
C:\Users\anuha\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openmdao\utils\general_utils.py:88: SetupWarning:'sub' : Attempted to connect from 'tgt.x' to 'cmp.x', but 'tgt.x' is an input. All connections must be from an output to an input.

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\anuha\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\testflo\test.py", line 418, in _try_call
func()
File "C:\Users\anuha\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openmdao\surrogate_models\tests\test_map.py", line 65, in test_comp_map
assert_near_equal(p['compmap.eff'], p['compmap.Nc']*p['compmap.Rline']**2+p['compmap.alpha'], tol)
File "C:\Users\anuha\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openmdao\utils\assert_utils.py", line 522, in assert_near_equal
% (actual, desired, error, tolerance))
ValueError: actual [3.6], desired [4.1895], rel error 0.1407089151450053, tolerance 0.1

Appreciate your help!

Comment: Hi, what version of numpy are you using?

Comment: Hi, it is numpy 1.21.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be a bug with this particular surrogate model with recent versions of `numpy` in a Windows environment. The bug has been logged [here](https://github.com/OpenMDAO/OpenMDAO/issues/2471) and will be addressed in a future release.

If this is your only error and you are not using surrogate models in your work, you should be fine.

If you need this test to pass you should be able to create a working environment with:

```
conda create -n OpenMDAO python=3.8 numpy=1.18 scipy=1.4
```

Alternatively, I would suggest running OpenMDAO in a Linux environment using [WSL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/about).